# Как сделать редирект на сервер (основное доменное имя)

Tags: хостинг, редирект, домен

Есть куча доменов 3 уровня, как можно сделать редирект с данных доменов, при том, что они не имеют своего хостинга. Нужно сделать редирект с них на основной домен, получается без файла .htacess, так как хостинг под домены 3-го уровня нет

Answer (score 1):

Можете прописать их в поле CNAME для основного домена в админке.

Если есть доступ к конфигам:
NGinx:

```
    server_name     sitename.com www.sitename.com;
```

Apache

```
    ServerName sitename.com
    ServerAlias www.sitename.com
```

Comment: А если мне нужно, чтобы на конкретный адрес на сервере редирект шел? Например: site.com/project1

Comment: тут зависит от конфигурации платформы - в частности от того, куда у вас есть доступ.